# US citizen applying for Schengen tourist visa while waiting for residency card

Tags: portugal

I'm a US citizen living in Portugal. I arrived with a temporary residence visa under the D8 program last year. I've since had 2 appointments with SEF (immigration office), both of which were canceled when I arrived because the "system was down." My next appointment will be 4 months from now, and then it will take another 3-4 months to get the residency card.

I'd like to be able to move freely around Europe. I've heard it could be possible to get a special case Schengen tourist visa issue through a country's embassy. Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, a tourist visa won't help you.  It only allows you to do something you're already allowed to do without a visa, which is to stay in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in a 180-day period -- a limit that you have already exceeded.  Your presence in Portugal is legal because of the pending application, but to be able to go to other Schengen countries, you need a valid type D visa.  I doubt you'll have a lot of luck getting another Schengen country to issue one, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, I appreciate it! Would love to hear anyone else’s perspective as well, but what you’re saying seems correct